# How to format date in javascript as DD-MMM-YYYY?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format

So the backend serves date to FE as: **'2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z'**

I am trying render on FE as **30-May-2019**

So...

```
let date = new Date( Date.parse('2012-01-26T13:51:50.417-07:00') );
```

I have been trying to use the [MDN Javascript Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

But how do you even start to modify a Date object and control to desired output?

Comment: you don't modify a date object, use the methods it has to output what you want (hint: `.getDate`, `.getMonth`, `.getFullyear`)

Comment: @JaromandaX Ahh got you, so it's a case building the desired output using like you say .getDate, .getMonth, .getFullyear.
Brilliant mate :)

Comment: or, if you're feeling adventurous, you can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) with an appropriate locale and options

Comment: There are a huge number of questions on [how to format a date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+format+date), please try to write your own code then ask if you have issues. The use of *Date.parse* in `new Date(Date.parse(string))` is redundant, `new Date(string)` will produce an identical result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to create a working function for this:

```
function formatDate(value) {
    let date = new Date(value);
    const day = date.toLocaleString('default', { day: '2-digit' });
    const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
    const year = date.toLocaleString('default', { year: 'numeric' });
    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}

formatDate('2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z') // 30-May-2019
```

Comment: This is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/257182).

Answer (score 1):

This uses the `toLocaleString()` method to get the month name, otherwise you would need an array of month names to match the output of `date.getMonth()` which would be just the number (0-indexed)(e.g. january would be 0)

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
```

```js
let date = new Date( Date.parse('2012-01-26T13:51:50.417-07:00') );

console.log(`${date.getDate()}-${date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })}-${date.getFullYear()}`);
```

Another approach would be to use the `toLocaleString()` for the rest of the formatting as well:

```js
let date = new Date( Date.parse('2012-01-26T13:51:50.417-07:00') );

dateFormatted = date.toLocaleString('default',{day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric'});
console.log(dateFormatted);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatDate(dateString) {
let date = new Date(dateString),
    day = date.getDay(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
      
return day + '-' + months[month] + '-' + year;
}
```

Predefined functions and an array.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `Array.prototype.indexOf()`?

Comment: Should be date.getDate() instead of date.getDay()